# AWS Rekognition - creating a dataset with a manifest file is always throwing an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-rekognition

I am creating a Dataset for a project in AWS rekognition by using a SageMaker formatted manifest file as below :

```
{
  "source-ref": "s3://custom-labels-console-ap-south-1-ddd62b2581/assets/pwst-new/1706007842/dot.jpg",
  "pwst-new-train_BB": {
    "annotations": [
      {
        "left": 99,
        "top": 66,
        "width": 202,
        "height": 335,
        "class_id": 0
      }
    ],
    "image_size": [
      {
        "width": 640,
        "height": 480,
        "depth": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  "pwst-new-train_BB-metadata": {
    "job-name": "labeling-job/pwst-new-train_BB",
    "class-map": {
      "0": "test"
    },
    "human-annotated": "yes",
    "objects": [
      {
        "confidence": 1
      }
    ],
    "creation-date": "2024-01-23T11:04:35.981Z",
    "type": "groundtruth/object-detection"
  },
  "cl-metadata": {
    "is_labeled": true
  }
}
```

I have added this file to an S3 bucket with correct Policy and still when I am trying to create a dataset, it's always throwing The manifest file contains too many invalid rows.

I tried adding the manifest file to different folders and also in the bucket that was created by default when launching Rekognition for the first time.

I also tried to just copy paste the contents of

```
aws rekognition list-dataset-entries
```

after creating a dataset by manually drawing blocks around directly uploaded images

Comment: Ok I got it and to anyone that faces the problem in the future (unless someone from AWS sees this and fixes it)!
you have to add a single line for each image in that manifest file, you have to create an invalid json file (don't use array and don't comma separate the entries)
JUST PUT THE OBJECTS ONE BELOW THE OTHER